# area map, scroll to id with responsive size

Tags: html

I've created an area map, scrolling to specific locations on the map. Everything is working fine until the image, used for the map, is being scaled to fit the screen size. Is there any way to rescale the coords used in "scrollTo", or scroll to an id of an area?

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="map.jpg" usemap="#clickmap" width="100%" height="auto">
    <map name="clickmap">
        <area class="link" shape="rect" coords="200,200,400,400" onclick="window.scrollTo(600,600);" href="#_">
        <area class="link" shape="rect" coords="600,600,800,800" onclick="window.scrollTo(200,200);" href="#_">
    </map>
    <script src="js/imageMapResizer.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $('map').imageMapResize();
    </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Mmh this is what the imageMapResizer you are using is claiming to do for you. It may have a bug. The [example page](https://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/example/) seems to be broken as well.

Comment: @PeterKrebs The example you've mentioned seems to work fine. Then again, its redirecting to a new page and not scrolling to a specific location on the same page. I believe the coords used don't take advantage of the resized image, but rather use the ones of the overall window, no matter what content there is, which is why I was wondering if the used method could be replaced by using id's

Comment: Either way you would have to scale the areas on your own then. I think you can simply multiply the coordinates by scale from the original size. I did something like that once in the past, but not with that package.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Ohhh, so a calculation with view-width / height? Good thought, thank you!